# Truffle migrate not updating dependency

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

I have created a ProductFactory contract which creates instances of another Product contract. 
Now I change code in the Product contract which is imported into the ProductFactory and run

```
truffle migrate
```

When I create a new Product instance using ProductFactory the new Product does not reflect changes (new methods, new variables) in the Product contract.
The migration file only deploys the ProductFactory like below:

```
 var ProductFactory = artifacts.require("./ProductFactory.sol");
    module.exports = function(deployer) {
      deployer.deploy(ProductFactory, {gas:4555000});
    };
```

What should I do to get the Product contract code updated?
Do I need to deploy the Product contract also separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it worked.
I was modifying the Product contract but not the ProductFactory which referenced the Product. I had not deployed the Product Contract separately. And the truffle migration does not redeploy only the dependency in such a case. (I guess thats how solidity is)
As a workaround I added a variable like below to ProductFactory

```
uint256 public version = 10;
```

Now everytime I make a change to Product I increment this value in ProductFactory and the changes are updated and redployed.

Answer (score 3):

you have to re-deploy the modified version of your contract after each change. You can do that by using the `--reset` flag with your migrate/deploy command, e.g. `truffle migrate --reset`